Show that $(a,r)$-torus is a regular differentiable surface
I have an exercise in my differential geometry course that asks me to prove that a torus is a regular surface.
My definition of regular surface is the following:
Def. A subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth regular differentiable surface if $ \forall p\in S$ exists $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and exists a map $\varphi:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that:

$\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorfic to an open disk.
$\varphi $ is a simple sheet of surface, that means $\Omega$ is open and connected, $\varphi$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, $\varphi$ is injective and its jacobian matrix has rank two in every point belonging to $\Omega$.
$\varphi(\Omega)\subseteq S$.
$\varphi(\Omega)$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ in $S$.

So, I take this function $\psi$ to parametrize the $(a,r)-$torus $T$ with $a>r$.
$$\psi: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3,(\phi,\theta)\longmapsto ((a+r\cos(\phi))\cos(\theta),(a+r\cos(\phi))\sin(\theta),r\sin(\phi))$$
I have found that:
$\psi$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$.
The jacobian matrix $Jac(\psi)(\phi,\theta)$ has rank two in every point $(\phi,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. I've proved that assuming that every submatrix of size $2\times 2$ has determinant equals to zero and showing an absurd.
The problem is that $\psi$ is not injective. So I have to find two restrictions of $\psi$,  $\psi_1, \psi_2$ such that the union of their images is $T$ and both are simple sheet of surface.
I tried with $\psi_1=\psi_{|(0,2\pi)\times (0,2\pi)}$ and $\psi_2=\psi_{|(-\pi,\pi)\times (-\pi,\pi)}$.
I started to check the injectivity. For $\psi_1$ I've found that it is injective by checking the definition with a long system of equation in $\phi$ and $\theta$, but I'm not sure if I treated every case in a proper way.
The real problem is to check the invertibility of $\psi_1$. And, if it's invertible, how can I check the continuity of the inverse to say that $\psi_1$ is an homeomorfism?
For $\psi_2$ I think that everything will be similar then.
Thanks.
